# Study the behavior of $\int_1^x \int_1^{t^2}\frac{\sqrt{1+u^4}}{u}\,du\, dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Let $$F(x)=\int_1^xf(t)dt$$
$$f(t)=\int_1^{t^2}\dfrac{\sqrt{1+u^4}}{u}du$$

> Write expression for $F'(x)$ and $F''(x)$. Determine when $F(x)$ is rising, concave up, has a relative Max or Min. Sketch a graph of $F(x)$.

This was a problem given to me in my high school calculus class. The focus at this time is the second fundamental theorem of calculus, which I assume is a big part in answering these questions. The first question was simple enough:
$$F'(x)=f(x)=\int_1^{x^2}\dfrac{\sqrt{1+u^4}}{u}du$$
$$F''(x)=f'(x)=2x*\dfrac{\sqrt{1+x^8}}{x^2}=\dfrac{2\sqrt{1+x^8}}{x}$$
just applying FTC2, these solutions are simple. The rest of the problem is just beyond me, though. Those look like questions that I would need a function for, and there's no way I'm integrating that function twice. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: The convexity can be determined just from the sign of the second derivative, while the monotonicity can be determined from the sign of the first derivative.

Comment: You can see that as long as $|x|>1$ the integral in $F'$ is positive, and it is negative for $|x|<1$.

Comment: The sign of $F''(x)$ only depends on the sign of that $x$ in the denominator.

Comment: $\displaystyle\int\frac{\sqrt{1+u^4}}u~du=\frac{\sqrt{1+u^4}-{\rm arccoth}\sqrt{1+u^4}}2$